# Java sockets java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, sockets

Getting Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException

at the last line of code, why? and how to fix... Thanks.

```
String ip = "XXX.XX.XX.XXX";
    int port = XXXXX;
    Socket socket = null;
    System.out.println("in function");
    socket = new Socket(ip, port);
    System.out.println("in function - After Socket");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("in function - After ObjectOutputStream");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Comment: if you are getting an `java.io.EOFException` while trying to get InputStream by `socket.getInputStream()` , its most likely a compatibility issue with other side / server side code.Also, at correct place, `java.io.EOFException` is usually a valid exception specifying that bytes have ended and there is nothing more to read.

Comment: what is at `ServerSocket` code?? May be ServerSocket is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The peer has already closed the socket. Possibly you sent it something it didn't understand. Unless it is a Java program that also uses object inout and output streams, it definitely won't understand.